# linq to sql fetching all the records category wise in the list<> and then looping

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

i am fetching all the records from the database with the help of this query organization wise. they become about 30-40 records

```
     List<PagesRef> paages = (from pagess in pagerepository.GetAllPages()
                  join pagesref in pagerepository.GetAllPageRef()
                  on pagess.int_PageId equals pagesref.int_PageId
                  where (pagess.int_PostStatusId != 3 && pagess.int_OrganizationId == Authorization.OrganizationID)
                  && pagesref.int_PageRefId == pagesref.Pages.PagesRefs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.int_PageId == pagess.int_PageId && m.bit_Active == true && (m.vcr_PageTitle != null && m.vcr_PageTitle != "")).int_PageRefId
                  select pagesref).ToList();
```

next the next step what i want to do is to loop through the above list as ***linq to object*** query without going to the database to generate 3 level hierarchical record. can some one give me some insight or idea how can i do it?

edit

```
    var parentrecord = paages.Where(n => n.Pages.int_PageParent == 0).OrderBy(m => m.Pages.int_SortOrder == null).OrderBy(m => m.int_PageId);

            foreach (var secondlevel in parentrecord) // if parentrecord found
            {
                var seclevel = paages.Where(m => m.Pages.int_PageParent == secondlevel.Pages.int_PageId).OrderBy(m => m.Pages.int_SortOrder == null).OrderBy(m => m.Pages.int_SortOrder);

                secondlevel.vcr_PageTitle = "parent";
                pagesreff.Add(secondlevel);   // if parentrecord found then loop and add in there

                foreach (var thdlevel in seclevel)
                {
                   var thirdlevel = paages.Where(m => m.Pages.int_PageParent == thdlevel.Pages.int_PageId).OrderBy(m => m.Pages.int_SortOrder == null).OrderBy(m => m.int_PageId).OrderBy(m => m.Pages.int_SortOrder);

                    thdlevel.vcr_PageTitle = "child";
                    pagesreff.Add(thdlevel);   // if parentrecord child found then loop and add in there

                    foreach (var thd in thirdlevel)
                    {
                        thd.vcr_PageTitle = "subchild";
                        pagesreff.Add(thd);   // if parentrecord child found then loop and add in there
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `ToList();` linq-to-sql go to database and get rows. After that, you have collection of objects and can do what you want with linq to objects:

```
var filteredList = paages.Where(someFilter);
```

there will be no new sql requests.

**Update**
Your problem is that you filter in navigation property, so you should load your navigation property with your first query. I'm not sure (linq-to-sql was many years ago:)), but this should help you (I assume that `m.Pages` is of type `Page`):

```
List<PagesRef> paages = (from pagess in pagerepository.GetAllPages()
                  join pagesref in pagerepository.GetAllPageRef()
                  on pagess.int_PageId equals pagesref.int_PageId
                  where (pagess.int_PostStatusId != 3 && pagess.int_OrganizationId == Authorization.OrganizationID)
                  && pagesref.int_PageRefId == pagesref.Pages.PagesRefs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.int_PageId == pagess.int_PageId && m.bit_Active == true && (m.vcr_PageTitle != null && m.vcr_PageTitle != "")).int_PageRefId
                  select pagesref).AssociateWith<Page>.ToList();
```

Comment: the problem is that sql profiler is showing that the sql is executed of what you have specified

Comment: Are you sure that you have ToList() at the end of linq-to-sql query? Could you show what linq to object query did you try? Is it work with PageRef entity or with navigation property?